# Should I make a bracha rishonah and acharonah on 1 ice cube?

Tags: halacha, blessing, water

1 ice cube is not a "m'lo lugmo" (majority of one's mouth), and it is also not the "norm" to eat ice cubes. Some people do this, anyway. For those that do, does it require a bracha? Does it matter if the ice cubes have a flavor, e.g.- frozen raspberry syrup?

Comment: See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=6rz4tkdzkmsC&pg=PA51&dq=ice+inauthor:bodner&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6xvXU9mUBIOHyATOnoHABQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=ice%20inauthor%3Abodner&f=false) if that will help you.....spoiler, no mention of ice cube [though he does talk about "ices" which I think are the same as "_ice cubes [that] have a flavor, e.g.- frozen raspberry syrup_"]

Comment: And "ice" anything is the only thing under "I" in *Halachos of Brachos* [with the arguable exception of "icing"]

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65628/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A beracha rishona is made on any amount of anything edible (Tur O.C. 210:1), including things which aren't so good (O.C. 204:1).  So you would make a shehakol.

Beracha Acharona could depend on a machlokes about shiurim of foods which are normally consumed more slowly.  Something which the normal way to consume it is to have less of it at a time, as I assume would be the case with ice cubes (since they are, by definition, freezing cold), is subject to a machlokes if it has a lower shiur.  The Taz (O.C. 210:1) assumes that whiskey has a lower shiur because people do not drink it at the normal rate of other drinks, and therefore it's shiur is whatever the standard amount is.  The Pri Megadim there cites a number of authorities who argue, among them the Elya Rabba and Magen Avraham.

Comment: +1. But what is "Tur O.C. 210:1"? I didn't look up 210, but AFAIK _Tur_ doesn't generally have subparts to its chapters. Is 210 an exception?

Comment: @msh210 sorry I use the shiras devora Tur which has the Tur split up by the corresponding se'ifim of the shulchan aruch.  I guess that is misleading.