# May one eat dairy immediately after tasting a meat item?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, meat-and-milk

I know that there are different customs regarding how long one must wait to eat dairy after eating meat.

Let's say one tastes a meat stew or soup to see if it needs more spicing, and this amount is less than an olive size, does one still need to wait to eat dairy? Does it matter if one tasted an actual piece of meat vs. a meat-based dish (such as chicken broth?) Do the rules regarding the amount of time to wait follow the same guidelines for the minimal amount needed for a bracha rishona (beginning bracha) as mentioned, [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65628/5275)?

Comment: Why might an olive size be relevant